# FlutterJNI.loadLibrary called more than once

Tags: flutter, push-notification, flutter-notification

FlutterJNI.loadLibrary called more than once
FlutterJNI.init called more than once

Notification is received when the app is terminated.
But when notification is clicked null check operator is used in the null value.
But notification data is present.

firebase_core: ^2.4.1
firebase_messaging: ^14.2.1

[image: Error Image]